# Process and upload video using getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, video, stream

I am trying to upload video from the users using the media capture interface recently introduced into javascript. Regardless of all the difficulties in browser compatibility, I can't even begin to understand the process of saving the video captured by the users.

I was thinking that I could somehow use ajax to push the streamed video up to the server, but be that as it may, I'm not even sure if I am approaching the problem appropriately.

I included my code, which currently only streams under chrome and opera.

```
function hasUserMedia()
{
    return !!(navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia);
}

if(hasUserMedia())
{
    var onFail = function(error)
    {
        alert("ERROR >> " + error);
    };

    var onPass = function(stream)
    {
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e)
        {
            //..what do I put here..?
        };
    }

    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true, audio:true}, onPass, onFail);
}
else
{
    alert("ERROR >> USERMEDIA NOT SUPPORTED");
}

function saveVideo()
{
    var connection = new XMLPHttpRequest();
    connection.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(connection.readyState == 4 && connection.status == 200)
        {
            alert("Your streamed video has been saved..!");
        }
    }
    //..what do I type here..?
    connection.open("POST","savevideo.php",true);
    connection.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't open a WebRTC connection to a server (though someone may be working on it...).  AFAIK the only method is to take a screenshot of each frame by capturing the video to a canvas, then sending each from to the server and compile the video there.

Check out:
https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/RecordRTC/

Also may be helpful:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/